# Call functions on events outside document.ready function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this doubt. I remember earlier I used to define functions for events outside `document.ready` function in jquery. Like

```
$(function(){
// some function calls
});


$("#some-id").click(function(){
// instructions
})
```

And this used to work, but today I tried the same. I wanted to trigger a click on a button when some other button was clicked. It didn't seem to work. Although, I tried to alert outside `document.ready` and it worked just fine.

I understand the use of `document.ready` but my click function should have worked right?

Comment: is the button dynamically added?check for error in console

Comment: Maybe the object #some-id is not yet loaded when it tries to associate the click event with the object.

Comment: No @guradio, the button is static!

Comment: to make sure your script works it's better to put the handlers inside dom ready when the elements are available. if its dynamic still you can use `on` handler inside document.ready

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry! I feel stupid! I was making changes to an existing code, written by someone else. He has js included in the head. It is obvious for that to not work as the element is not included when my function is read!

Thanks guys!